# SwiftUI darken modifier

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI has a helpful ViewModifier called brighten, does anyone know how to do the opposite and darken a view? I'd hoped passing in a negative value would do the trick, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Are you talking about dark mode?

Comment: No, I'm talking doing something like this: `MyView().brighten(0.5)` that brightens a particular view.

Is there a way of doing a darken effect?

Comment: View has brightness modifier nor brighten. Check this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view. Please check the below answer and let me know if it works for you!! I'm using xcode beta 5.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For darken the View, You can give negative value to brightness modifier like this,

```
MyView().brightness(-0.5)
```

Comment: Thank you Anjali, that works great! 

I was sure that was one of the first things I'd tried, maybe there was another problem somewhere else that was stopping it working initially.